# Program thats asks for a number then prints out all its factors, 150 --> 2,3,5,5

Tags: python-3.x

```
n = int(input("What number do you want factored out"))

def factors(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return i
            n = n/i
    return factors(n)

print(factors(n))
```

I'm currently using the current code, however I can only get the first factor. Can I not use recursion to repeat the code and generate all factors?
Is there a better way to approach this question?

Comment: Fun side effect of this code too, entering a prime number (except 2) will cause an infinite loop. Double check your logic and step through this by hand with an easy example (e.g. 10) and see where your logic breaks down.

Comment: Do you want just prime factors or all factors?? Do you also want negative factors??

Comment: Just factor that multiply up to that number... questions was poorly worded. 150/2 = 75, 75/3 = 25, 25/5 =5 , 5/5 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
def factors(n):
    f = []
    while n != 1:
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                f.append(i)
                n //= i
                break
    return f
print(factors(150))
```

Or, with recursion:

```
def factors(n):
    if n == 1:
        return []
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return [i] + factors(n // i)
print(factors(150))
```

Both output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to produce the OP's expected output in the title, not the mathematical definition of factors.

Comment: May I ask what //= does? Is that just basic division?

Comment: @Pallof `//` is integer division, so `a // b` is equivalent to `int(a / b)`, and `a //= b` is equivalent to `a = a // b`.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword essentially terminates the execution of the function. Any statements immediately following a `return` statement will never be reached. So as soon as you find a factor and do `return i`, your function ends. Maybe you're confusing `return i` and `print i`? Alternatively, add it to an array and pass that down through the next recursive function call.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done recursively, but it's probably best to do this algorithm iteratively because it's faster and more readable:

```
def factors(n):
    for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            yield n // i

print(list(factors(25)))
```

This is far from industrial strength but should be reasonably fast. It allows duplicates, so you may wish to call `set()` before `list()`. You only need to iterate up to the square root of `n` and for any number `i` that is a factor, include the number that can be multiplied by `i` to get `n` as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why the range start from 1 and ends at n+1

Comment: It just looks at every number and checks to see if it divides evenly--as mentioned, efficiency wasn't taken into consideration. I can update with a more efficient answer if you want.

Comment: No, no. no need to be so kind. I'mm just confused because don't I want to start at 2 because 1 will be a factor no matter what?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but then it'll be left out of the results unless you add it by hand.

Comment: No problem. I added more efficient versions--I hate to go around promoting slow factoring functions. Let me know if there's anything off here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the factors then you can do:

```
import numpy as np
fact = lambda x : np.arange(1,x+1)[x % np.arange(1,x+1)==0]

fact(100)
 array([  1,   2,   4,   5,  10,  20,  25,  50, 100])

fact(27)
 array([ 1,  3,  9, 27])
```

if you just want the prime multipliers:

```
def facts(x,m=None,i=2):
    if m is None:
        m = []
    if x //i >0:
        if x % i ==0:
            m.append(i)
            facts(x // i,m ,i)
        else:
            facts(x,m,i+1)
    return(m)    

facts(150)
  [2, 3, 5, 5]

facts(2*3*5*7*9*10)
  [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7]
```