# find the number of distinct prime divisors of G using python programming?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

i have just wasted my 2 hours only for solving this programming question.if any one knows the trick of doing then please share it.question is given below.

You have given an array A having N integers. Let say G is the product of all elements of A.You have to find the number of distinct prime divisors of G.

Input Format
The first argument given is an Array A, having N integers.

Output Format
Return an Integer, i.e number of distinct prime divisors of
G.
Constraints
1 <= N <= 1e5
1 <= A[i] <= 1e5

For Example

Input:
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Output:
2
Explanation:
here G = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
and distinct prime divisors of G are [2, 3]

Comment: SO is not here to do your assessments for you, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you done already? Please don't post your homework here.

Comment: This, as most questions which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump, is too broad to be answered. Please state whether you would appreciate help according to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Hint: 1, 2, 3, 4 already divide `1*2*3*4`, and finding divisors of 1, 2, 3, 4 would probably be easier

Comment: The distinct primes of array A is the answer.  So program a sieve for primes and pass it the elements of array A, discard duplicates.

Comment: check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509521/program-thats-asks-for-a-number-then-prints-out-all-its-factors-150-2-3-5-5/51510051#51510051) . Just add `np.unique(facts(1*2*3*4))` You can upvote the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694459/find-total-count-of-distinct-prime-in-given-array-using-python/51753479#51753479

Answer (score 2):

Since this seems to be a homework question, I'll give some pushes in the right direction.

Theoretically, this is a very simple thing to do. Anyone can write code that loops through an array and multiplies its elements. It is also very easy to find pseudocode (or even real code) for factorizing a number into its prime factors.

However, this approach will not work here, since we will be dealing with HUGE numbers. The maximum value of G, given your constraints, is (10⁵)^(10⁵) = 10⁵⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰. This by far exceeds the number of electrons in the observable universe. We cannot factorize such huge numbers.

But luckily we don't need to know the value of G. We are only required to calculate it's prime factors, but we don't need to know the value of G to do so. So instead you will have to factorize the individual numbers in the array. I would recommend something like this code:

```
factors = set()
for num in A:
    f = factorize(num) # Function that returns the set of prime factors in num
    factors |= f # Add all elements in f to factors
```

You were only interested in the *distinct* prime factors, so using a `set` will take care of that. Just add everything, and it will automatically throw away any duplicates. `factorize(x)` is a function you will need to write that takes a number as argument and return the set of prime factors.

Good luck!