# Find total count of Distinct Prime in given array using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, prime-factoring

The problem is like this -
You have given an array A having N integers. Let say G is the product of all elements of A. You have to find the number of distinct prime divisors of G.
Example - 
Input :
A = 1, 2, 3, 4
Output :
2

Explanation :
Here g = 1*2*3*4
and distinct prime divisor of g are 2 and 3
To total count of distinct prime divisor = 2

Below is the code i wrote but the output which i am getting is wrong -

```
  class prime:
  # @param A : list of integers
  # @return an integer
      def prime(self,num):
          if(num>1):
              for i in range(2,num):
                  if(num%i==0):
                      break
                  else:
                      return num


      def solve(self, A):
          prod = 1
          tot = 0
          for i in range(0,len(A)):
              prod = prod*A[i]
          for i in range(0,len(A)):
              if(self.prime(A[i])):
                  if(prod%self.prime(A[i])==0):
                      tot = tot+1
          return tot



  A = [1,2,3,4]
  prime().solve(A))
```

Comment: You code works fine for me. You just have indentation issues. I would love to put the working code as an answer but that doesn't make sense because I didn't do anything new.

Comment: See: [When is it appropriate to tag multiple languages in my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question) I have removed the [tag:java] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the give inputs and outputs by the OP i understood that OP wants to count the number of primes which can completely divide the prod (product of element) and give remainder as 0.
Input 1 by OP - g = 1*2*3*4 and distinct prime divisor of g are 2 and 3. Total count of distinct prime divisor = 2
Input 2 by OP - g = 96*98*5*41*80 and distinct prime divisor of g are 2,3,5,7 and 41. Total count of distinct prime divisor = 5

Code for the above problem -

```
class Solution:
# @param A : list of integers
# @return an integer
def prime(self,num):
    if(num==1):
        return 0
    for i in range(2,(num//2+1)):
        if(num%i==0):
            return 0
    return num


def solve(self, A):
    prod = 1
    tot = 0
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        prod = prod*A[i]
    for i in range(1,(prod//2+1)):
        pr = self.prime(i)
        if(pr):
            #77145600
            print("Prime :",pr)
            if(prod%pr==0):
                tot = tot+1
    return tot



A = [96,98,5,41,80]
print(Solution().solve(A))
```

But for this code, the response time is very high. For this input - 96,98,5,41,80 the response time was more than 5 hours. Can anyone provide a better solution for it?

I found a better solution then the above mentioned by me -

Updated new code -

```
# Python Program to find the prime number
def prime(num):
    if(num==1):
        return 0
    for i in range(2,(num//2+1)):
        if(num%i==0):
            return 0
    return num

# Python Program to find the factors of a number
def findFactors(x):
   # This function takes a number and finds the factors
   total = 0
   for i in range(1, x + 1):
       if x % i == 0:
           if(prime(i)!=0):
               print("Prime : ",prime(i))
               total+=1
               print("Total : ",total)
    return total               

# change this value for a different result.
num = 77145600
findFactors(num)
```

The findFactors function first finds the factors of given number and then by using prime function I am checking whether the found factor is prime or not. If it is a prime number then I am incrementing the total by 1.
Execution time is 45 seconds on my system.

Comment: Yes sir thats the output which i wanted but your code takes to much time to generate the output. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
class prime:
# @param A : list of integers
# @return an integer
  def prime(self,num):
      if num == 2:  # changes
          return num  # changes
      if(num>2):  # changes
          for i in range(2,num):
              if(num%i==0):
                  break
              else:
                  return num


  def solve(self, A):
      prod = 1
      tot = 0
      for i in range(0,len(A)):
          prod = prod*A[i]
      for i in range(0,len(A)):
          if(self.prime(A[i])):
              if(prod%self.prime(A[i])==0):
                  tot = tot+1
      return tot



A = [1,2,3,4]
print(prime().solve(A))
```

Lines that were changed were commented with # changes

Comment: I am getting wrong output for an input A = [96,98,5,41,80]. For this input i am getting output as 2 but the correct output is 5

Comment: @User but there are only 2 prime numbers in A.

Comment: @No_one_is_here: The code should be such that it works for any value of `A`, not just the one given in the question.

Comment: @Bazingaa I cannot answer this question. Clearly, there are only 2 prime numbers in [96,98,5,41,80]. The correct output cannot be 5 (which is what OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt

from itertools import count, islice

class Prime:

    def prime(self, n):
        if n < 2:
            return False

        for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n) - 1)):
            if n % number == 0:
                return False

        return True

    def solve(self, A):

        prod = 1
        tot = 0

        for i in range(0, len(A)):
            prod = prod * A[i]

        if(prod<2):
            return 0

        if(prod == 2 or prod == 3):
            return 1

        for i in range(2, prod/2+1):
            if(self.prime(i) and prod % i ==0):
                tot  =tot+1

        return tot

A = [1,2,3,4]
print(Prime().solve(A))
```